# Try parsing from the next special symbol occurence if parser is failed

Tags: parsing, haskell, attoparsec

Suppose there is some parser:

```
valid :: Parser String
valid = string "valid" <* skipWhile (/= '\n')
```

It could be used for getting `"valid"` strings from the multiline text:

```
> parseOnly (many $ valid <* optional endOfLine) "valid\nvalid\nvalid"
Right ["valid","valid","valid"]
```

If there is a line where `valid` Parser fails further text will not be parsed at all:

```
> parseOnly (many $ valid <* optional endOfLine) "valid\ninvalid\nvalid"
Right ["valid"]
```

How to get `Rigth["valid", "valid"]` instead? I thought that [`try`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/attoparsec-0.10.4.0/docs/Data-Attoparsec-Text.html#v%3atry) could be helpful here somehow, but not sure how to continue parsing from the the next line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using parsec:

```
-- parser for the rest of the line
rest = manyTill anyChar (eof <|> char '\n' *> return ()) <* optional (char '\n')

-- change this to accept lines, but Just the valid ones
valid :: Parser (Maybe String)
valid = (Just <$> string "valid" <|> const Nothing <$> anyChar) <* rest

-- filter out Nothing
valids = catMaybes <$> many valid

-- Run
*Foo> runParser valids () "input" "valid1\ninvvalid2\nvalid3"
Right ["valid","valid"]
*Foo> runParser valids () "input" "valid1\nvalid2\nvalid3"
Right ["valid","valid","valid"]
```

Here i have to make a buggy hack: `const Nothing <$> anyChar` so `valid` consumes always at least something, otherwise I can't give it to `many`. However using `Maybe` you can rewrite your parser as you need (eg making newline mandatory)

Very similar approach is applicable with attoparsec, sorry for spoiling the joy of making it yourself.

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import Data.Attoparsec.Text
import Control.Applicative
import Data.Maybe
import Data.Text

-- parser for the rest of the line
rest = skipWhile (/= '\n') <* optional endOfLine

-- change this to accept lines, but Just the valid ones
valid :: Parser (Maybe Text)
valid = (Just <$> string "valid" <|> const Nothing <$> anyChar) <* rest

-- filter out Nothing
valids = catMaybes <$> many valid
```

```
*Main> parseOnly valids "valid1\nvalid2\nvalid3"
Right ["valid","valid","valid"]
*Main> parseOnly valids "valid1\ninvalid2\nvalid3"
Right ["valid","valid"]
```

Comment: `<* optional (char '\n')` part is redundant in `rest`. Nice parsec solution, but question is about attoparsec.

Comment: attoparsec is very similar. Some primitive parsers are named differently, but overall structure is identical.

Comment: This `Maybe` approach seems to be reasonable, thanks. Also, I removed all `Text`-related pack-unpacking stuff, if you don't mind.